# Splitting Column of a CSV (Pandas DataFrame) file using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with 2 columns and 100 rows. The 2nd column's information looks something like "***my name is nash (1994)***". I want to take the year **(1994)** out of this 2nd column and want to **create a new column (3rd column)** name it (**Header of the new column**) as the **Year** and **pass those years** in that new column in a **new CSV file**. I hope my description my clear, if not please feel free to ask any questions.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Year'] = df['Name'].str.extract(pat='([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])')
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.extract(pat='([a-zA-Z].*) \(.*')
```

For more explanation refer this:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Hello Mr. Agarwal,

I hope you are doing great.

Thank you for your help. 

It is working. But, the YEARS from the 2nd column is still there! So, I want to remove the years completely from the 2nd column and put them into the 3rd one as the image shows.

Thank You